# Liquid Tight Flexible Conduit generator span

Tags: electrical, conduit

I can't find a specific answer for this situation.  I know that flexible conduit can be used as a 6 foot whip for luminary and "other equipment". It can be used over 6 feet.  The question that I can't seem to answer is if a whip exceeds 6 feet and needs supported every 4.5 foot span, does that include the support of the 6 foot whip.

Ie does a 6 foot whip become 4.5 feet between supports.   If a 10 foot section of flexible conduit 5 feet from a building has to be supported ever 4.5 feet?

So ultimately, I am asking if a 10 foot section of flexible conduit, can span 6 feet between a building and a generator without additional support between the two?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't running an underground section of conduit between the generator pad and the house? That sounds like a real nasty one for severe physical damage (imagine your conduit getting mowed...)

Comment: Very good point. it is in an area that won't be exposed to mowers, traffic etc. It is also in the path of gasline, house main feed and shrub roots that I don't desire to deal with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NEC doesn't define a "whip" or uses of a whip. For each raceway type the code gives support requirements and exceptions. Since you are referencing 4.5' you must be referencing Liquidtight Flexible Metalic Conduit LFMC, since Non-metallic LFNC requires 3 ft support. LFMC Section 350.30 says:

> **350.30 Securing and Supporting.** LFMC shall be securely fastened in place and supported in accordance with 350.30(A) and (B).
>
> (A) Securely Fastened. LFMC shall be securely fastened in place by an
> approved means within 300 mm (12 in.) of each box, cabinet, conduit
> body, or other conduit termination and shall be supported and secured
> at intervals not to exceed 1.4 m (4'/2 ft).
>
> Exception No. 1: Where LFMC
> is fished between access points through concealed spaces in finished
> buildings or structures and supporting is impractical.
>
> Exception No. 2: Where flexibility is necessary after installation,
> lengths shall not exceed the following:
>
> (1) 900 mm (3 ft) for metric designators 16 through 35 (trade sizes
> 1/2 through l 1/4)
>
> (2) 1200 mm (4 ft) for metric designators 41 through 53 (trade sizes 1
> 1/2 through 2)
>
> (3) 1500 mm (5 ft) for metric designators 63 (trade size 2.5) and larger
>
> Exception No. 3: Lengths not exceeding 1.8 m (6 ft) from a luminaire
> terminal connection for tap conductors to lumi-naires, as permitted in
> 410.117(C).
>
> Exception No. 4: Lengths not exceeding 1.8 m (6 ft) from the last
> point where the raceway is securely fastened for connections within an
> accessible ceiling to luminaire(s) or other equipment.
>
> (B) Supports. Horizontal runs of LFMC supported by openings through
> framing members at intervals not greater than 1.4 m (4'/2 ft) and
> securely fastened within 300 mm (12 in.) of termination points shall
> be permitted.

None of the exceptions allow the last 6' of LFMC as you described to not be supported. You could argue that generator vibration would require flexibility as described in Exception 2, but you may not win that argument because you may need to justify how a support would limit flexibility.

Comment: Thanks!.  Yes It is LFMC and "whip" was for description.  Your interpretation matches mine, but exception 4 is where I scratch my head at the definition of "or other equipment."  My assumption is that specific to other equipment in the ceiling. I'm assuming the intent around 6' is for grounding purposes and not to facilitate unsupported conduit use.   Thanks again!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "other equipment" is within a ceiling because otherwise exception (2) would be completely redundant.